# Generate 1M unique random keys with alpanumeric subset

Tags: c#, random, unique

I want to generate 1M random (appearing) unique alphanumeric keys and store them in a database. Each key will be 8 characters long and only the subset "abcdefghijk n pqrstuvxyz and 0-9" will be used.

The letters l,m,o and w are ditched. "m and w" are left out because of limited printing space, as each key will be printed on a product in a very small space. Dropping m and w enabled to increase the letter size with 2pt, improving readability. l and o were dropped because they are easily mixed up with 1, i and 0 at the current printing size. We did some testing characters 1,i, and 0 were always read correctly, l and o had to many mistakes. Capitals were left out for the same reason as 'm and w".

So why not a sequence? A few reasons: The keys can be registered afterwards and we do not want anyone guessing the next key in the sequence and register somebody else's key. Appearance: we don't need customers and competition to know we only shipped a few thousand keys.

Is there a practical way to generate the keys, ensure the uniqueness of each key and store them in a database? Thanks!

Comment: Gartman writes: " Appearance: we don't need customers and competition to know we only shipped a few thousand keys. "  From my experience , they **will** figure it out.

Comment: The trick is to obtain an even distribution of duplicates.

Comment: @starbolin - You could of course just generate unique keys and not have any duplicates.

Comment: @Ramhound yes, at the time I hadn't done the math and thought he wanted to reuse keys.  I didn't realize the magnitude of the overage he was generating.   Others have covered the topic so I`m bowing out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: @CodeInChaos pointed out a problem: `System.Random` isn't very secure, and the sequence could be reproduced without a great deal of difficulty.  I've replaced `Random` with a secure generator here:

```
var possibilities = "abcdefghijknpqrstuvxyz0123456789".ToCharArray();
int goal = 1000000;
int codeLength = 8;
var codes = new HashSet<string>();
var random = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
while (codes.Count < goal)
{
    var newCode = new char[codeLength];
    for (int i = 0; i < codeLength; i++)
        newCode[i] = possibilities[random.Next(possibilities.Length)];
    codes.Add(new string(newCode));
}
// now write codes to database

static class Extensions
{
    public static byte Next(this RNGCryptoServiceProvider provider, byte maximum)
    {
        var b = new byte[1];
        while (true)
        {
            provider.GetBytes(b);
            if (b[0] < maximum)
                return b[0];
        }
    }
}
```

(the Next method isn't very fast, but might be good enough for your purposes)

Comment: This is a great answer except for a major problem. This does not guarantee unique values. This of course would be good to generate a random key.  You could improve on the code by using a `while loop` within the `for loop` on the condition that the generated string does not already exist in the HashSet.

Comment: Actually, it does ensure unique values.  `HashSet<string>.Add` checks if the value exists in the collection before actually adding it.  It returns a `bool` so you can know, but all we really need to know is when we reach the goal of 1M keys.

Comment: Learn something new every day. =)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tim S. I will certainly go through your solution.

Comment: Your code doesn't fulfill one of the requirements, namely "we do not want anyone guessing the next key in the sequence". If the attacker knows the algorithm and observes a single code, he can calculate all past and future codes generated with your code.

Comment: Hm...it wouldn't be computationally trivial, but I can see how a secure or true random source would be much better than simply using `System.Random`.

Comment: excellent solution, and it is reasonably fast. faster than all my attempts anyway. awesome. The key is to have a code space much larger than the number of codes you want, so you minimise collisions

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a practical way to generate the keys, ensure the uniqueness
>   of each key and store them in a database?

Since this is a single operation you could simply do the following:

1) Generate A Single Key
2) Verify that the generated key does not exist in the database.
3) If it does exist generate a new key.
3b) If it does not exist write it to the database
4) Go Back to Step 1

There are other choices of course, in the end it boils down to generating a key, and making sure it does not exist in the database.

You could in theory generate 10 million keys ( in order to save processing power ) write them to a file.  Once the keys are generate just look at each one and see if it already exits in the database.  **You likely could program a tool that does this in less then 48 hours.**

Answer (score 1):

1 million isn't much these days and you can probably do that on a single machine fairly quickly. It's a one-time operation after all.

1. Take a hashtable (or hashset)
2. Generate random keys and put them into it as keys (or directly if a set) until the count is 1 million
3. Write them to the database

My quick and dirty testing code looked like this:

```
function new-key {-join'abcdefghijknpqrstuvxyz0123456789'[(0..7|%{random 32})]}
$keys = @{}
for(){$keys[(new-key)]=1}
```

But PowerShell is *slow*, so I'd expect C++ or C# do very well here.

Answer (score 1):

I encounter a similar problem once.. what I did is create a unique sequence YYYY/MM/DD/HH/MM/SS/millis/nano and get its hash code. After that I use the hash as a key. Your client and your competitor won't be able to guess the next value. It might not be full proof but in my case it was enough!

Comment: This would generate hash codes that contained 'illegal' characters per his requirements. Besides....this is basically how the `Random` class works.

Comment: Ramhound, `Random` doesn't use a hash at all.

Answer (score 0):

To actually get the random string, you can use code similar to this:

```
Random rand = new Random(new DateTime().Millisecond);
String[] possibilities = {"a","b","c","d","e","f","g","h","i","j","k",
    "l","n","p","q","r","s","t","u","v","x","y","z","0","1","2","3","4",
    "5","6","7","8","9"};
for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; ++i)
{
    System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
    for (int j = 0; j < 8; ++j)
    {
        sb.Append(possibilities[rand.Next(possibilities.Length)]);
    }
    if (!databaseContains(sb.ToString()))
        databaseAdd(sb.ToString());
    else
        --i;
}
```

Comment: You can append characters, so you can just write `char[] possibilities = "...".ToCharArray()`. Much easier to read and write.