# how to generate a unique random number?

Tags: java, arrays, methods, random, bluej

when storing to student may happen to have the same id, so how can i avoid the duplication, I have tried the while loop and the for each loop but it did not work

```
public void addStudent(Student student)

{

student.setId(ganerateNewRandom("aa", 2));

students.add(student);

}






  public String ganerateNewRandom(String prefix, int number)
 {

  Random random = new Random();

    StringBuffer ret = new StringBuffer(prefix);


    for(int i=0;i<number;i++) ret.append(random.nextInt(10));


    return ret.toString();


}
```

Comment: There are hundreds of duplicates of this topic here on SO; please use the search facility before posting...

Comment: Use an `int seed` variable which value would be unique for the application and it will increment every time you use it. If you're in a multithreaded environment, you should use `AtomicInteger`.

Comment: There is a realy good example. Check this:

"Generate 1M unique random keys with alpanumeric subset"


  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11053377/generate-1m-unique-random-keys-with-alpanumeric-subset

Comment: Why is random important in your context?

Comment: [Obligatory xkcd](http://xkcd.com/221/).

Answer (score 5):

I suggest you just imitate the way it is done in databases:
Start with `id=1` and each time enlarge it by 1: `id++`.
That way each student will have unique id and you don't have to generate random numbers.

Comment: Problem with that it is not taking into account multi-threading and multiple JVMs.

Comment: Nobody mentioned multiple JVMs or threading.

Answer (score 3):

Use [java.util.UUID](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/UUID.html) to generate proper unique ID.

example:

```
UUID myID = UUID.randomUUID();
```

It uses [RFC 4122: A Universally Unique IDentifier (UUID) URN Namespace"](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4122.txt) methodology.

Comment: Nice tips! 
well i suppose they still exists a tiny chance to get a duplicate isn't it ?

Comment: @Gab Its pretty solid and standard practice for UID generation in Java. Refer to RFC 4122 to get more information.

Comment: Wikipedia: "In other words, only after generating 1 billion UUIDs every second for the next 100 years, the probability of creating just one duplicate would be about 50%."

Answer (score 2):

Just tell me all of this is not used to generate a database id. if it's the case you are going the worst way, id generation MUST be delegated to the database

Answer (score 1):

To make sure your random numbers are unique you must store all previous random numbers.

How you store them depends on how many you plan to generate.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend checking out Google's repository with regards to random number generation [here](https://code.google.com/p/javarng/)